# Simplify $(1+i)^{2017} + (i-1)^{2017}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I had to simplify complex number $(1+i)^{2017} + (i-1)^{2017}$ where $i= \sqrt {-1} $ on a test but I could not do it as the exponent is so large.

Correct answer was $2^{1009}i$

I tried to convert it to trigonometric form and got
$(\sqrt 2)^{2017}(\cos(\frac{2017\pi}{4}) +i\sin(\frac{2017\pi}{4})) \quad + \quad (\sqrt 2)^{2017}(\cos(\frac{2017\cdot 3\pi}{4}) +i\sin(\frac{2017\cdot 3\pi}{4})) $

But I need help going on from here

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$e^{i\theta}=\cos \theta+i\sin \theta$.

$(i+1)=\sqrt{2}\cdot e^{\frac{\pi i}{4}}$,$\qquad $ $(i-1)=\sqrt{2}\cdot e^{\frac{3\pi i}
{4}}$.

$(i+1)^n+(i-1)^n=2^{\frac{n}{2}}\cdot (e^{\frac{n\pi i}{4}}+e^{\frac{3n\pi i}{4}})$.

$2017\equiv 1\pmod 8$.

$(i+1)^{2017}+(i-1)^{2017}=2^{\frac{2017}{2}}\cdot (e^{\frac{\pi i}{4}}+e^{\frac{3\pi i}{4}})=2^{\frac{2016}{2}}\cdot 2i=2^{1009} \cdot i$.

Comment: Yeah, That's how I would do it too ! (+1)

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** $$(1+i)^2 = 1+2i+i^2 = 2i$$

So $$(1+i)^{2n+1} = (1+i)(1+i)^{2n}= (1+i)2^ni^n$$

and $$(i-1)^{2n+1} = -(1-i)^{2n+1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from your trigonometric form, remember that $\cos(x+2\pi)=\cos(x) \implies \cos(\frac{2017\cdot 3}{4}\pi)=\cos(\frac{6051}{4}\pi)=\cos(1512\pi+\frac{3}{4}\pi)=\cos(\frac{3}{4}\pi)$

I believe you can take it from here :)